# floor() in php not working

Tags: php, floor

```
<?php
    echo gettype ( 5.00 );                                  // return double
    echo gettype((5));                                      // return integer
    echo gettype(((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100));             // return double

    echo floor(5.00);                                       // return 5
    echo floor(5);                                          // return 5
    echo ((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100);                      // return 5
    echo floor(((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100));               // return 4



    var_dump(5.00);                                         // return float(5)
    var_dump(5);                                            // return int(5)
    var_dump((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100);                   // return float(5)
    var_dump(intval(5));                                    // return int(5)
    var_dump(intval((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100));           // return int(4)

    echo gettype(intval(((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100)));     // return integer
    echo floor(intval((167.00-158.65)/167.00*100));         // return 4
?>
```

Why floor function in php not working in last case?

How to get `5` from last statement?
Is there any other function or method in php to get exact least amount?

Comment: [`Returns the next lowest integer value (as float) by rounding down value if necessary.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

Comment: [Here is a good explanation.](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/)

Comment: the last echo statement gives int value not FLOAT...So,next lowest integer will be 4

Comment: @Kunal, my 2nd statement also return 5 while passing same int value.

Comment: So,use gettype ( $var ) to check What is the datatype of each variable actually...And how php rconsiders them actually....

Answer (score 8):

That behaviour is caused by limited precision of floating point numbers. The last case is of type `float` (check it with `var_dump`), and the Manual says:

> Warning
>
> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: **for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....**

Source:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php